# How to use DOM event onloadeddata in HTML5 audio element through Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, dom

I am trying to use DOM event onloadeddata using angularjs. So far I was able to do this for click event, but was not able to replicate the same thing for onloadeddata event. What I am doing wrong?

```
.directive('audioLoaded', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.on('onloadeddata', function() {
            console.log('loaded');
            //scope.audioLoadedFromURL = true;
        });
    }
};
});
```

What I want to do is to change the value of a angularjs variable, after the audio element has loaded the data from the url.

Comment: Check my updated answer. It works now as you need.

Comment: Let me know if you have further confusions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `addEventListener` on `elem[0]` like

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

 <audio controls audio-events autoplay>
  <source ng-src="{{url}}" type="audio/mp3">
 </audio>

</body>
```

Controller

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.mp3");
});

app.directive('audioEvents', function () {
    return function ($scope, $element) {
      $element[0].addEventListener("loadeddata", function () {
        console.log('loadeddata');
        // you can $rootScope.$broadcast...
      });

    }
});
```

For you work around and further experiment here is the link to working [PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/ofn2MgzltxCSbroMCalv?p=preview)

Comment: This does not seem to work for me, and for the record it does not gives out any errors either.

Comment: WHat do you get? error on console? Provide more detail.

Comment: Ok check this plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/ZYkQVJGhtG6DiZmMgj3K?p=preview

Comment: It did not gave any errors on the console. Simply console.log didn't execute after the audio file has been loaded. To check whether the DOM onloadeddata got executed, I added onloadeddata="alert()" to audio element, and the alert poped up, but angularjs directive didn't execute

Answer (score 0):

use the `addEventListener` on `elem[0]` element

```
elem[0].addEventListener("loadeddata", function () {
        console.log('loaded');
});
```

Comment: You edited the answer to look similar to mine. Anyways i have no issues.